# Is there a way to integrate Firebase Functions with Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-cloud-functions, chatbot, chatfuel

I'm creating a chatbot using chatfuel and storage data on firebase, I would like to know if it is possible to get this events and send then to google calendar. Thanks

Comment: If you haven't done so, try the [Firebase: retrieving data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data).`This document covers the basics of retrieving database data, how data is ordered, and how to perform simple queries on data. Data retrieval in the Admin SDK is implemented slightly differently across different programming languages.` Also after you have extracted the data you needed from firebase, you can use [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) to create an event in Calendar API.